# Copy a subset of a 2d vector?

Tags: c++, vector, subset, sdl-2

I am attempting to copy a subset of a 2d vector in order to implement screen culling for a tilemap. To do this, I need to obtain a subset of a std::vector> by using two points: starting point and the ending point.

Here is how I am doing it currently:

```
typedef struct tile_t {
    int x;
    int y;
    SDL_Texture* texture;
}

std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> Map::GetTilesInRange(SDL_Point starting_point, SDL_Point ending_point) {
    int starting_tile_x = floor(starting_point.x / TILE_WIDTH);
    int starting_tile_y = floor(starting_point.y / TILE_HEIGHT);
    int ending_tile_x = ceil(ending_point.x / TILE_WIDTH);
    int ending_tile_y = ceil(ending_point.y / TILE_HEIGHT);
    starting_tile_x = clamp(starting_tile_x, 0, this->width);
    starting_tile_y = clamp(starting_tile_y, 0, this->height);
    ending_tile_x = clamp(ending_tile_x, 0, this->width);
    ending_tile_y = clamp(ending_tile_y, 0, this->height);
    printf("\n");
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", this->width, this->height);
    printf("(%d, %d); (%d, %d)\n", starting_tile_x, starting_tile_y, 
                                    ending_tile_x, ending_tile_y);
    std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> return_val(this->tiles_parsed.begin() + starting_tile_x, this->tiles_parsed.begin() + ending_tile_x);
    return return_val;
}
```

The issue is that I am only rendering a certain portion of the selected range. Why is this the case and how can I fix it?

Comment: On the the first look, it doesn't appear that you are using the y bounds at all.

Comment: Could you please be a little more explicit about your question? I kinda get the idea of it but still don't understand what is the "selected range" you are talking about? Also, why are there no y-coordinates mentioned in `return_val`?

Comment: You only copy one line. Since there is no single contiguous block you'll have to loop over each line (starting_tile_y to ending_tile_y) and perform the same copy but from/into different offset.